# Codeigniter - base_url can put in the $this->load->view or not?

Tags: php, codeigniter

can ask the `base_url` can put in the `$this->load->view` or not? if have can give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the `view.php file`:

```
<?php 
$this->load->helper('url');   
?>

<script src="<?= base_url('assets/js/example.js'); ?>"></script>
```

It you want to use it definitely in `$this->load->view`:

```
$this->load->helper('url'); 
$this->load->view('path_to_view',['burl' => base_url()]);
```

Now in `path_to_view.php` you can use `$burl` variable which contains `base_url()`.

Comment: $this->load->view can put another controller function at inside?

Comment: @gancheesiang, it can use value of this function inside the `load->view`. You can try to use [variable functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)